# How can I have 3 Futures run asynchronously and display each answer?

Tags: scala

I'm learning scala and I want to run 3 futures asynchronously and get an answer for each one.
But I can't get it to work.

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
def f_Fail(): Future[String] = Future {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      throw new RuntimeException("わざと失敗")
    }
def f_success(): Future[String] = Future {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      "future!"
    }
    val f1 = f_success()
    val f2 = f_success()
    val f3 = f_Fail()
    val future =for {
        n <- f1
        m <- f2
        p <- f3
    } yield n+"\n"+m+"\n"+p
Await.ready(future,Duration.Inf).value.get match {
      case Success(v) => println(v)
      case Failure(e) => println("not found")
    }
```

### Expected results

"future!"

"future!"

"not found"

### Actual result

"not found"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `for`-comprehension is so-called "syntactic sugar" for nested `flatMap` calls and finally a `map`. In your case, the `for`-comprehension can be effectively re-written as:

```scala
val future = f1.flatMap(n => f2.flatMap(m => f3.map(p => n+"\n"+m+"\n"+p)))
```

In the context of `Future`s, the `flatMap` method requires the `Future` upon which its called to be completed before the result is available for the following step. Simplifying for clarity, consider the following:

```scala
f1.flatMap(n => f2.map(m => m + n))
```

In order for the lamdba passed to the `flatMap` method to be invoked, the result of the calculation must be known.

Effectively, `flatMap` calls represent the concept of a direct dependency on a previous computation being executed successfully. In the same way, its "sugared" counterpart, the `for`-comprehension, represents the same.

This means that if any step of the chain fails, the overall result will be failed, which is what you are experiencing in your example.

What you can do is the following:

```scala
val f1 = f_success().recover(_ => "not found")
val f2 = f_success().recover(_ => "not found")
val f3 = f_Fail().recover(_ => "not found")

for {
  n <- f1
  m <- f2
  p <- f3
} {
  println(n)
  println(m)
  println(p)
}
```

Notice that:

- `Future`s are "eager", i.e. the computation is started immediately when the `Future` itself is instantiated. This means that the first three lines effectively start each computation independently and (given enough threads and resources) concurrently or even in parallel.
- each `Future` defines how to be recovered by returning the `"not found"` string in case of error (which is the case for `f3`).
- the side effect (`println`) is performed as part of the `for`-comprehension itself, allowing you to avoid blocking on the synchronous context -- in this case, the `for`-comprehension without `yield` is equivalent to executing the final step inside a `foreach` instead of a `map`, which is better suited to express side effects.

Now, let's say that you want to start your `Future`s lazily by simply wrapping their definition in a function. You'll notice that suddenly the execution doesn't necessarily take advantage of multiple threads and cores and takes 3 seconds instead of one, as in the following example:

```
def f1 = f_success().recover(_ => "not found")
def f2 = f_success().recover(_ => "not found")
def f3 = f_Fail().recover(_ => "not found")

for {
  n <- f1
  m <- f2
  p <- f3
} {
  println(n)
  println(m)
  println(p)
}
```

This is because of the semantics of `flatMap`. You can solve this problem by using a construct that doesn't imply some form of direct dependency between the steps of the calculation, like `zip`:

```
def f1 = f_success().recover(_ => "not found")
def f2 = f_success().recover(_ => "not found")
def f3 = f_Fail().recover(_ => "not found")

for (((n, m), p) <- f1.zip(f2).zip(f3)) {
  println(n)
  println(m)
  println(p)
}
```

This runs again in ~1 second as you might expect.

Alternatively, if you want to still return the result as a `Future`, you can of course use `yield` as follows:

```scala
val future = for (((n, m), p) <- f1.zip(f2).zip(f3)) yield s"$n\n$m\n$p"
```

You can read more about `for`-comprehensions [here on the Scala book](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html).

Comment: I want to use Await Main.scala:29: error: type mismatch;
  found: Unit
  required: scala.concurrent.Awaitable[?]
I get an error saying.

Comment: If you want to use the result of the `Future` you need to use `yield`, I added the modified version at the end of the answer. `future` can be given to the `Await.ready` or `Await.result` methods.

Comment: found : Throwable => String
[error] required: PartialFunction[Throwable,?]
[error] def f1 = f_success().recover(_ => "not found") Do you get this error?

Comment: No, you can run it successfully on Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/NeoQIdjYRo6Vcaflzphjtg/35 (I had to use a fixed thread pool because the global fork-join pool caused an error there -- but worked when using the Scala REPL locally, so I guess it's a Scastie-specific limitation).

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem, looks like you are running Scala 2.12. You can fix it by replacing `(_ => "not found")` with `{ case _ => "not found" }` as in this worksheet: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/NeoQIdjYRo6Vcaflzphjtg/39

Comment: Or alternatively you can define separately a `PartialFunction` as a way to define the `recover` procedure as you can see here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/NeoQIdjYRo6Vcaflzphjtg/41